# Trying to use 'cyl_bessel_i' from STD C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to use the `cyl_bessel_i` function from cmath. My understanding is that this function was added to the standard library from C++ 17 onward. Yet, I am being told that the function is undefined.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <cmath>
...
void Kaiser( int order, float b, vector<float>& kaiserWindow)
{
    ...
    float bessel = fabs( cyl_bessel_i( 0, beta) );
    ...
}
```

Adding `std::` and/or `using namespace std` is not resolving the issue.
I'm working in VS 2019.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please give a [mre]. Be sue to include the exact command used to compile with the compiler (name and version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not given any reproducible example, I have tried to use the function std::cyl_bessel_i with settings as under:

[image: project configuration]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{

    // spot check for ν == 0
    double x = 1.2345;
    std::cout << "I_0(" << x << ") = " << std::cyl_bessel_i(0, x) << '\n';
    std::getchar();
}
```

The output was as under:
    I_0(1.2345) = 1.41886

I would not be able to figure out why it is not working for you, since I am not aware you the project configuration you are using. May be you can try or share more details.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yup. This is helpful, thank you. Too new to give you an upvote but I marked your answer as correct. Thanks again!